# Flutter: static late field has already been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

My login page uses `AnimationContoller` and whenever I tried to sign out after I logged in, this error pops up

Here is the declaration:

```
  static late final AnimationController topTextController;
  static late final Animation<Offset> topTextAnimation;
```

this is how I Initialized it:

```
static void initialize({
    required TickerProvider vsync,
    required int createAccountItems,
    required int loginItems,
  }) {
    topTextController = AnimationController(
      vsync: vsync,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );

    topTextAnimation = _createAnimation(
        begin: Offset.zero,
        end: const Offset(-1.2, 0),
        parent: topTextController);

})
```

this is my dispose code:

```
   static void dispose() {
    topTextController.dispose();
    bottomTextController.dispose();
    for (final controller in [
      ...createAccountControllers,
      ...loginControllers,
    ]) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
  }
```

NOTE: I have call both initialize function as well as the dispose function in another page.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide minimal, *complete* code that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Most importantly, you haven't shown how you declared the `static` member that the error is referring to.  I presume it's about `topTextController`?  Did you declare it `final`?  If so, don't declare it `final` if you expect to be able to call `initialize` more than once. (Or alternatively enforce that you never call `initialize` multiple times.)

Comment: @jamesdlin I have edited my post adding how I declared the variable. The only part I left out is when I call the initialize and dispose functions on my login page class. 

Your assumption is correct, its about the `topTextController` and I did declared it `final`. Thank you for your suggestion, I will tweak my code and see how it goes. So sorry for the inconvenience !